# VB.Net Splash Screen Doesn't Go Away

Tags: vb.net, splash-screen

I am using the built in functionality to define a splash screen using vb.net in VS2008.
In Me.Startup, I'm calling a function which does a DB version check, then updates if required.  This function then writes to a label, using an invoke if required to write the status.
Everything functions fine, all the DB updates complete, but the splash screen just never disappears afterwards.  It's there while the updates are running, and when the last code has executed, the main form appears as expected, but the splash screen is still in the background.
When I close the main form, the splash screen keeps running.
I've tried adding code to manually close the splash screen form when the code has run, but to no effect.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing initialization/update actions on application start, I would suggest not using the built in splash screen.

Why don't you create a Main() module to start up your application, display the splash screen, do the DB check, hide the splash screen, and then load the main form.

Comment: I am using http://www.getdotnetcode.com/GdncStore/free/Articles/VB%20NET%20Sub%20Main%20Procedure.htm to walk me through it, as I've never written my own Main() routine before.